# Monitor mode on macbook 2015 hardware in (kali) linux

Tags: kali-linux, macintosh, broadcom

After installing Kali Linux on a USB Stick with persistence enabled and live booting it (via refind) on my macbook pro (late 2015) the wifi did not work. I found out how to install the [right drivers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin) from git.kernel.org 
and this enabled using wifi.

Still  **monitor mode** does not work.

When I try it with 'airmon -ng start wlan0' for example to get the interface into monitor mode, I get the following error.

```
phy0    wlan0        brcmfmac    Broadcom Corporation Device 43ba (rev 01)
Failed to set wlan0mon up using ip
command failed: No such device (-19)

        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
```

(After checking with iwconfig the interface is still in managed mode.)

According to [this site](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211/), if I got it right, (search for monitor mode) the brcmfmac driver, which I am using, does not support monitor mode yet.

- Is it possible to find a way to make it work anyways?
- Can I maybe use another driver instead? Or add support for monitor mode myself?

Thanks a lot, any help is really appreciated, because I am totally stuck.

( **Chipset**         BCM43602
 **PCI Device ID**   14e4:43ba
 **Driver name** brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin )

Comment: Why kali?; What is your use case?

Answer (score 2):

Get a usb wifi adapter and that will fix all your problems
here a list of [kali Linux WIFI adapter](https://kalitut.com/usb-wi-fi-adapters-supporting-monitor/) that works just perfect

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the card doesn't support monitor mode, but there is a work around. You actually have to run `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/brcm_monitor0` which will create another interface called prism0, you can confirm this by re-running `ifconfig` you then will run an `airodump-ng prism0` to begin capturing packets. You will need to do this every time you want to put the card into "monitor mode"

Comment: with a configuration provided in the question i.e. `brcmfmac` driver, trying to write to `/proc/brcm_monitor0` gives `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: and according to the [`brcmfmac wiki`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211) monitor mode is not supported

Comment: prism is another brand. maybe you have got a wifi stick, which is not the OP case.

Comment: I just checked and nope no wifi stick, just the builtin Broadcom. The directions are here https://pentestmac.wordpress.com/tag/macbook-wireless-monitor-mode/ . Prism0 is an alias interface.

Answer (score 0):

The `BCM43602` definitely support monitor mode. It works on macOS.
Here is simple utility for macOS to dump wireless traffic: [airport-sniffer](https://github.com/zhovner/airport-sniffer). It works successfully with BCM43602. You can also turn on monitor mode on macOS with `Wireless Diagnostics.app`.

During to this wiki https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211 only brcm(**s**)mac support monitor mode. But BCM43602 uses brcm(**f**)mac driver that not support monitor mode. So looks like monitor mode not supported in Linux yet.